# Node-Red - JSON over MQTT - Remove String

Tags: json, mqtt, node-red

Question about JSON via MQTT
Raspberry pi w/gps sending location data to server via MQTT. all the information is received by the server fine, however, the payload is a string when received.

How to remove the "" from my json.

Raw from GPS Module:

3/31/2017, 2:13:29 PMec04f460.a91eb8
msg.payload : Object

{ "class": "TPV", "tag": "RMC", "device": "/dev/ttyUSB0", "mode": 3, "time": "2017-03-31T18:14:48.000Z", "ept": 0.005, "lat": 29.844941667, "lon": -81.277976667, "alt": 2.2, "epx": 45.649, "epy": 10.829, "epv": 4.945, "track": 171.72, "speed": 0.046, "climb": 0, "eps": 91.3, "epc": 9.89 }

directly to MQTT server via Node-Red

Server Receives:

3/31/2017, 2:16:26 PMnode: d369167f.b8ea58
trolley281/gps : msg.payload : string[251]

"{"class":"TPV","tag":"RMC","device":"/dev/ttyUSB0","mode":3,"time":"2017-03-31T18:17:46.000Z","ept":0.005,"lat":29.844945,"lon":-81.277986667,"alt":2.9,"epx":45.649,"epy":10.829,"epv":4.945,"track":166.53,"speed":0.005,"climb":0,"eps":91.3,"epc":9.89}"

As a string...

Anyone have an idea how to clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the palette for the JSON node, it will convert a JSON string to a JSON object (or vis versa).

[image]